# Correct way to design and test this class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I am developing an interpreter and want to do internal testing of an "execute" method that interprets a model. The execute method doesn't have input or output, so the only way to test the method (at least from what I know) is to mock the internal method calls to see that they are executed in the right order.

Currently I have the following classes:

1. `ExecutableInstance` - model class that can be executed.
2. `ExecutableInstanceFactory` - singleton class (implemented as an enum) that creates executable instances, with different methods depending on the parameters it is given.
3. `ModelAnalyzer` - singleton class that contains methods to analyze the model

The interpreter calls the `execute()` method of the `ExecutableInstance` class, which then calls the `ModelAnalyzer` to understand the internal executable instances in the model. It then creates new `ExecutableInstance`s using the `ExecutableInstanceFactory` and then calls their `execute()` method depending on how the model is defined.

My idea is to mock the `ExecutableInstanceFactory` class so that it returns mock `ExecutableInstace`s which I can then test for execution order. But this would mean that I have to inject the `ExecutableInstanceFactory` into the `ExecutableInstance`. Since it is a singleton, it would be dumb and stupid to pass it as a parameter. I thought of using Google's Guice for DI... but I'm stuck trying to do this.

Is my direction correct? If so, how should this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a few smaller methods out of this execute method. For example - one method for parsing which returns something to the execute method, then another one which does something with the returned data and returns other data etc. Then you would not have to test the Execute method, only the smaller ones. This will also allow you to detect bugs easier.

Comment: Thought about that, but this would break the encapsulation of the `ExecutableInstance` class. Is this considered OK today?

Comment: As long as the methods are meaningful I don't think the encapsulation will break since every method can be used in another situation - for example if you want only to parse the code and not execute it.

Answer (score 1):

> The execute method doesn't have input or output

So behaviour should be verified on the class' collaborators (use mocks).

> Since it is a singleton, it would be dumb and stupid to pass it as a parameter.

The fact that you have problems testing shows you flaws in your design. Get rid of a singleton and inject the collaborators.